# After deploying the script in target environment ,how to ensure that it is not modified?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

We are providing powershell script to end users to do some activity.

If they change the script by themselves then it may not work as intended.

Is there any way to lock the scripts so that once we shipped that end user can't rewrite any thing in it?

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

- Sign it.
- Put an ACL on the script that blocks modification by end users.

Comment: +1 for the first point. This is one of the reasons MS gave the ability to sign PS scripts.